# Is there a cruise ship from Hong Kong to Taiwan?

Tags: hong-kong, taiwan, cruising

I am in Hong Kong. I am wondering if I can find a cruise ship to Taiwan. I noticed there is a cruise ship docked in the harbor but I am not sure where it's heading.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I've edited your question to put it more in line with StackExchange and TSE standards as suggested in the site [tour] and [help]; our format is ill-suited to price-shopping. Your question could be further strengthened by indicating what initial research you have attempted, such as web searches, or which Hong Kong travel guides you have consulted.